# How to get blockdiag directives rendered to HTML?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, blockdiag

I'm trying to add programmatically-rendered diagrams to my reStructuredText documentation, which I render to HTML with Sphinx.

Per https://lpn-doc-sphinx-primer-devel.readthedocs.io/extensions/blockdiag/blockdiag.html , I've added `sphinxcontrib-blockdiag` to conf.py:

```
# conf.py
...
extensions = [
  'sphinxcontrib.blockdiag',
]
...
```

Per http://blockdiag.com/en/blockdiag/sphinxcontrib.html, I've installed `sphinxcontrib-blockdiag` with `pip`:

```
$ pip install sphinxcontrib-blockdiag
...
$ pip freeze
...
blockdiag==3.0.0
...
sphinxcontrib-blockdiag==3.0.0
...
```

I created a `.rst` file with the example from  http://blockdiag.com/en/blockdiag/sphinxcontrib.html verbatim:

```
A Heading
=========

Some text before the diagram.

.. blockdiag::

    blockdiag admin {
      top_page -> config -> config_edit -> config_confirm -> top_page;
    }

Some text after the diagram.
```

The resulting HTML renders with no diagram. When I open the rendered HTML in my browser, it essentially looks like this:

> **A Heading**
>
> Some text before the diagram.
>
> Some text after the diagram.

**How do I make the blockdiag/Sphinx integration work as advertised?** How can I get whatever parts of the software pipeline to perform as claimed and include a diagram in the rendered HTML?

---

Below is the `sphinx-build ./source/ ./build/` output -- note the warning about a "textsize" attribute:

```
$ sphinx-build ./source/ ./build/
Running Sphinx v7.2.6
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
writing output...
building [html]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 1 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
copying assets... copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
done
writing output... [100%] index
WARNING: dot code 'blockdiag admin {\n  top_page -> config -> config_edit -> config_confirm -> top_page;\n}': 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'textsize'
generating indices... genindex done
writing additional pages... search done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 1 warning.

The HTML pages are in build.
$
```

Note that the official documentation example at http://blockdiag.com/en/blockdiag/sphinxcontrib.html does not mention any "textsize" attribute, so I assumed this was an ignorable warning.

Moreover, searching the official documentation site for "textsize" yields no hits.

---

Just for kicks, I tried sticking a guessed-at `textsize` option in the `.. blockdiag::` section of `index.rst`:

```
A Heading
=========

Some text before the diagram.

.. blockdiag::
   :textsize: 5

    blockdiag admin {
      top_page -> config -> config_edit -> config_confirm -> top_page;
    }

Some text after the diagram.
```

...this generated an outright error with `sphinx-build`:

```
/home/user/dev/scratch/sphinx-blockdiag/source/index.rst:27: ERROR: Error in "blockdiag" directive:
unknown option: "textsize".

.. blockdiag::
   :textsize: 5

    blockdiag admin {
      top_page -> config -> config_edit -> config_confirm -> top_page;
    }
```

Comment: It's an old extension that might not be supported for your environment. Do you see any error messages? Alternatively, I've used https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/graphviz.html.